# Get attribute name with simple HTML DOM?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to get attribute values in `data-date`, inside the `<ul>` tag

Sample Code:

```
<ul class="media-list">
    <li class="media-item" data-date="2014-04-24 07:30:29">Tes</li>
    <li class="media-item" data-date="2014-04-25 08:30:29">Tes</li>
    <li class="media-item" data-date="2014-04-26 09:30:29">Tes</li>
</ul>
```

I want to get those values inside the list, below is the desired output:

`(2014-04-24 07:30:29, 2014-04-25 08:30:29, 2014-04-26 09:30:29)`

Comment: [Read the DOCs](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_find) `$ret = $html->find('li[data-date]');`

Comment: @user3566810 Have you checked my answer. I checked it in my system. It  gives what you need. Please check it out my answer. If the solution is good for you, accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will work perfectly to get each li's data-date value.

```
<?php

include('inc/simple_html_dom.php');

$html = str_get_html('<ul class="media-list">
                      <li class="media-item" data-date="2014-04-24 07:30:29">Tes</li>
                      <li class="media-item" data-date="2014-04-25 08:30:29">Tes</li>
                      <li class="media-item" data-date="2014-04-26 09:30:29">Tes</li>
                      </ul>');
foreach($html->find('ul.media-list li.media-item') as $li) 
{
    echo $li->{'data-date'}."<br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to use this clumsy syntax:

```
$li->{'data-date'};
```

Comment: can you give me example ?

Answer (score -1):

You can try it:

```
include "simple_html_dom.php";
$html = str_get_html('<ul class="media-list">
    <li class="media-item" data-date="2014-04-24 07:30:29">Tes</li>
    <li class="media-item" data-date="2014-04-25 08:30:29">Tes</li>
    <li class="media-item" data-date="2014-04-26 09:30:29">Tes</li>
</ul>');

$tag = "data-date";
$html_lis = $html->find('li');

foreach($html_lis as $row_li) {

    echo $row_li->$tag;
    // Or echo $row_li->{'data-date'}
}
```

Comment: its return 0 for data-date ?